# Can I use Omnigraffle instead of Axure and achieve the same results?

Tags: tools

I have been looking to start a new job the new year and lots of UX position mention requires Axure in the specs. I have heard of it but I have never used it I have used Omnigraffle and Balsmicq.

are there some substantial differences between Axure and Omnigraffle. can i say safely that 'I have used Omnigraffle instead' or they're totally different tools?

thanks

Comment: learn basic HTML and you can use your Omnigraffle or Balsamiq wireframes to create far more sophisticated interactive prototypes than Axure can achieve. Plus, HTML/JS/CSS are actual good tools to know outside of prototyping, something Axure isn't. Plus it's free.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a software review, not a specific UX issue.

Comment: Axure is great if you're going to use it to its full potential, including its ability to quickly prototype logic and generate fully annotated specifications. If you literally want to produce wireframes, you're better off in something like Balsamiq or Omnigraffle. But I agree, an off topic can of worms.

Comment: Axure isn't rocket science. Grab the demo version, spend an afternoon with it, and you'll be up to speed.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Omnigraffle is more or less a wireframe tool.

Axure is a tool for interactive prototypes (you can do wireframes nevertheless).

sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Eh...I think it's a matter of degrees rather than 'one is this, the other is that'. Most Axure work is wireframes based. Yes, you can get a level of interactivity out of it above and beyond some other tools--and that's used at times--but I'd say it's still mostly just a 'high fidelity' wireframing tool.

Answer (score 1):

> are there some substantial differences between Axure and Omnigraffle

Yes. But nothing unsurmountable. Both are wireframing tools. Axure adds interaction design capabilities--though I tend to be cautious in telling people to rely too much on them.

I suggest you grab the demo version of Axure and spend a little time with it. I think you'll can get the overall idea of how it works and what it does within an afternoon of playing with it.

Also, be cautious of places that are only looking for people that know a particular piece of software. They should be hiring you based on your UX skills and overall creative thinking abilities. Anyone can learn a particular piece of software.

Comment: Excellent point about businesses placing too much value on easily-learned skills such as using software.

Answer (score 0):

Omnigraffle is for diagrams or wireframes.
Axure is for demos or prototypes. It creates html and javascript codes for you. You can draw diagrams and wireframes too.

You can say "I used Axure instead of Omnigraffle."
But you CANNOT say "I used Omnigraffle instead of Axure".